# How to match linker symbols for minimal Win32 linking with MinGW?

Tags: linker, cygwin, mingw, undefined-reference

I would like to make some Win32 API calls from within a Cygwin program, but I'm unable to import `windows.h` without problems with redefinitions. I don't need the entire header, but only a few select functions. So I thought I could just import those manually with identical declarations. But this doesn't seem to work.

Here is an example program where I try to import `Sleep()`:

```
#define DECLSPEC_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define WINAPI __stdcall
#define WINBASEAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
WINBASEAPI void WINAPI Sleep(DWORD);

int main() {
   Sleep(1);
   
   return 0;
}
```

However, I am still unable to properly match the linker symbol:

```
$ nm -gC libkernel32.a | grep -i sleep
00000000 T SleepEx@8
00000000 I _imp__SleepEx@8
00000000 T Sleep@4
00000000 I _imp__Sleep@4
```

Linker error:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o a.out -mwindows
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/TEMP/ccY6MURi.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___Z5Sleepm@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't have this problem if I `#include <windows.h>`. Even though I have matched the declarations exactly, why is the symbol different?

Comment: Try adding `extern "C"` to the declaration of `Sleep`.

Comment: That was it. I missed the extern "C". Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use `#include <windows.h>`? That's the proper way to do it.

You're linker error indicates the issue is related to the C++ calling convention. Have you tried with `gcc` instead of `g++`?

All those complexities should be covered if you just use `#include <windows.h>`.

Comment: I'm unable to import windows.h without problems with redefinitions.

Comment: Use `#include <windows.h>` and then show us the gcc or g++ command line and the full text of all the errors and warning you see.

Comment: @Zhro Why would you need to redefine what is already correctly defined in `windows.h`? Just start your program with `#include <windows.h>` and then define `main`.

Comment: I can't do that because of duplicate definitions.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you only have `#include <windows.h>` followed by `main` there should be no duplicate definitions, unless your build environment is broken.
If that is the case you can try a different build environment like the standalone MinGW-w64 build https://winlibs.com/ to see if the simple program builds.

Comment: There are several Cygwin includes which contain duplicate definitions that conflict with those found in `windows.h`. That is the entire premise of my question.

Comment: Is it an option to use native MinGW-w64 instead of Cygwin?